# How to enable Bluetooth when the phone is tapped with NFC tag?

Tags: bluetooth, tags, nfc, ndef

In our project I have a requirement where if some one taps their NFC enabled phone with my NFC tag, then bluetooth should be enabled in their phone. What NDEF message(message type etc) should be stored in the NFC tag?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to achieve this is by having an application installed on the phone that handles the tag and enable the Bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Install nfc tools. Click add a record.Add bluetooth device and write into tag